# Make pm2 log to console

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am running a node webserver using pm2. Since pm2 spawns another process and redirects stdout and stderr to files, I have to look somewhere else for the logs. Ideally, I would like to have the node process output to the same console window that I've run pm2 from. Otherwise, I would settle for pm2 run the node process with an active console window and have stdout and stderr of the node process write to that console window. How can this be achieved? I'm on a windows machine.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

I believe you can also see the **stdout** and **stderr** of a process that is running daemonized by the command `pm2 logs` or `pm2 logs [app-name]`.

Comment: accepting this answer since it addresses the first log being missed with th `--no-daemon` flag

Comment: what do you mean by "deamonized"?

Answer (score 31):

you can easily achieve that by starting another terminal/console and run this command

```
 pm2 log
```

logs everything to the terminal except console.log

```
 pm2 logs
```

logs everything to the terminal and console.log

**notice the 's' in the second command**

Answer (score 15):

Found the answer (their documentation is not that great), just added the `--no-daemon` flag, seems to have done it. Although, it appears that it's still logging to the file (even when using the flag) on the first uptime. Once the process gets restarted (I'm watching for file changes) it starts logging out to the console

Comment: What worked for me was
`pm2 start --no-daemon src/index.js --watch`

Answer (score 7):

programmatically you can do something like this:

```
const pm2 = require('pm2')

pm2.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(2);
  }
  pm2.start([
    {
      script             : "server.js",
      output: "/dev/stdout",
      error: "/dev/stderr",
    },
  ]
    , function(err, proc) {
      if(err) {
        throw err
      }
    });
})
```

Comment: You can also set output and error options to be `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/sterr` respectively.

Comment: It would be good to stdOut to console!! Do anyone of you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

Direct to the app running that you want to monit logs

```
pm2 logs <app id or app name> --lines 50
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `--attach` flag might be the best option here.

From [docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/):

> To start an app and check logs stream use the --attach option:
> `$ pm2 start api.js --attach`
> When quitting via Ctrl-C, the app will still run in background.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to run pm2 in background of an nginx-based docker container. Added a shell script into `/docker-entrypoint.d/` which just runs `./node_modules/.bin/pm2-runtime start ./ecosystem.config.cjs &`. The & makes pm2 run in background, but all the stdout is unaffected - it all gets mixed in with normal nginx stdout.