# How to access a Node.js application log lauched through pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I've been developing a Node.js application using Socket.IO, Express, MySql and https and everything worked fine until I "deamonized" it with pm2. Now, my socket seems somehow unresponsive and I'd like to debug it. **The problem is that I can't seem to find where the console.log() function from this code outputs its text anymore.**

*I case you'd like to know, all my pm2 processes are online and I can refresh my pages from the client side. But there should be a fonction on the server that triggers an event on the client side when something happens in the database and it does not.*

Could tell me where the output from consone.log() is goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PM2 docs:

> PM2 allows you to easily manage your application’s logs. You can
>   display the logs coming from all your applications in real-time, flush
>   them, and reload them. There are also different ways to configure how
>   PM2 will handle your logs (separated in different files, merged, with
>   timestamp…) without modifying anything in your code.

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/

And other SO question:

[Make pm2 log to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075460/make-pm2-log-to-console)

Comment: I have already tried *pm2 flush* and then *pm2 logs <my process>* but nothing shows on the log when I connect a new client even though i have a console.log() function called everytime a new client connects.

Comment: It seems that I had that EADDRINUSE problem again so I had to kill a process and then start only one process not to get the WebSocket error. After that *pm2 logs <my processes>* finally showed me what I expected. The problem was elsewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the logs with the `pm2 logs` command 
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that while your server is running and you use

```
pm2 log
```

all logs will be displayed except

```
console.log()
```

all you have to do is instead of pm2 log, run

```
 pm2 logs
```

note the "s" at the logs. hope this helps